# How to protect API endpoints from being accessed outside of application

Tags: angular, api, security, heroku, mean-stack

I am fairly new to web development. I created a MEAN stack app, and i'm interested in making my API's inaccessible outside of my application.

For example, I have an endpoint that looks something like this (this is a fake one for obvious reasons): `https://fakeserver.herokuapp.com/getAllUsers`. I use this within my app to do all types of stuff. However, if someone were to hit that link directly in a web browser, they would get all the data associated with that endpoint. Is there a way to protect that from happening? (assuming someone gets access to that URL)

Comment: use authorization for this. Want token from all requests and allow only validated token requests

Comment: I would recommend using a secure, HTTP Only cookie to hold your authentication information, usually, but not always, in the form of a JWT token. This information should be one-way encrypted so it's only decode-able by your API.

Answer (score 0):

### Welcome to Web Development

This is a very common thing in web development. Making all data associated to a user secure. It looks like you are using Heroku.

Now firstly just to make sure, you should never store private data on an angular app (unless you only allow access to an IP and manage which I would not recommend).
The reason for not hosting private data on angular is because all angular code is publicly accessible, even if you hide it. Angular is a client side app meaning all the code is rendered on the clients machine.

If you haven't done so already I would recommend is looking in to REST API's, this creates a layer where any private code can be placed rendering it on a private server hidden from public.

Once you have set up REST API's your code is no longer publicly accessible but your API's can still be accessed if someone finds your API URL. To solve this I would recommend looking in to OAuth 2.0

Happy coding!

Comment: Sorry looks like I need to re look into heroku and update my answer!